# Mandrill PHP library - FROM field

Tags: php, mandrill

How can I set a proper FROM field for the PHP Mandrill library?

In Java, I can use:

```
from = "Some Description <noreply@domain.com>";
```

If I try the same in PHP, I get an error:

> Validation error: {"message":{"from_email":"The username portion of the email address is invalid (the portion before the @: Some Description

Only emails with FROMs like this get through:

```
$from = "noreply@domain.com";
```

In case it matters, here's how I send an email:

```
$from = "Some Description <noreply@domain.com>";
$message = array("subject" => $aSubject, "from_email" => $from, "html" => $aBody, "to" => $to);

$response = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async = false, $ip_pool = null, $send_at = null);
```

Comment: the previous one works fine with php show us code which gives you error.

Comment: You mean the first one?

Comment: for mandrill php library see how to set the sender's name here https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html there is a parameter called as from_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html it has two parameters in request
`from_email` and `from_name` when we pass

`$from = "Name <email>"`,

It is not accepted by mandrill hence it throws error , To pass a name  you need to pass from_name with name value.

Comment: Thanks, it worked flawlessly. Also, I didn't down vote. I was mislead by the Java API not requiring the two strings to be separated.